# Form submit with href function in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, model

I have implemented code which has belongs to form submit with href link.

While submits form post action is php file and href link has to popup the model of that php file. while am posting values should carry out. I mean user enter email ID to display in php file. I added my source here please suggest me how call php file and function in same form submission.

```
<form action="login.php" id="form1" method="POST"  onsubmit="loadLoginBox();" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="email" value="" input-sm">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >
</div>  
</form>
```

loadLoginBox() implemented in js file

Comment: Use ajax to submit your form. Do a quick search on the web of "submit form with ajax", you should find what you're searching for